# How to create Custom form fields on Glpi framework

Tags: php, mysql

We are using  [Glpi](http://glpi-project.org) for tracking harware information.We want to create custom form fields out on coming defaults with glpi.This change will be in `helpdesk.public.php`.

Is there any idea about how can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't go down that road. It would become a hard to mantain installation.

You can save a lot of problems using a well-mantained, community-supported (paid options are available too ;)), plugin like Fields:
http://plugins.glpi-project.org/#/plugin/field

Adding a new field to main form or too a new tab is quite easy this way.

According to the plugin info possible fields type are :

1. Header (title bloc)
2. Text (single line)
3. Text (multiple lines)
4. Number
5. Dropdown (always a tree dropdown)
6. Yes / No
7. Date
8. Date / Hour
9. Glpi User list

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [FormCreator](https://plugins.glpi-project.org/#/plugin/formcreator) plugin.